# Ruby Calling Class Method from Instance Method

Tags: ruby, methods, class-method, instance-methods

What is the syntax for calling a class method from an instance method?
Suppose I have the following

```
class Class1
    def initialize
       #instance method
       self.class.edit
       puts "hello"
    end

    def self.edit
       #class method
       "ha"
    end
end

c= Class1
```

When I run this code, I get no outputs.

Comment: Try `Class1.new`. `initialize` is an instance method, so it must be invoked on an instance of `Class1`. `Class1.new` creates the instance, invokes `initialize` on it and then returns the instance.

Answer (score 5):

You don't get any output because you don't do anything with the result of that call, plus you don't actually create an instance with `new`, you just make `c` an alias for that class. If you change it a bit you get this:

```
class Class1
    def initialize
       #instance method
       puts self.class.edit
    end

    def self.edit
       #class method
       "ha"
    end
end

c= Class1.new
```